# How to check if all GridView Textboxes are filled using vb.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

So I have my textboxes in a template field in a gridview. I want 6 fixed textboxes on page load. I figured that part out. If all the 6 textboxes are filled I want to add a new row when a dropdown value is selected. The dropdown value would then populate the new row as it appears. How would I do this? I know the basic setup but I just need the bit of code that checks if all the textboxes are filled.

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gvReq.Rows

    Dim Index As Integer = row.RowIndex
    Dim ReqText As TextBox = CType(gvReq.Rows(Index).FindControl("txtReqText"), TextBox)
    Dim chkReq As CheckBox = CType(gvReq.Rows(Index).FindControl("chkReq"), CheckBox)
    If ReqText.Text = "" Then
        ReqText.Text = reader("RequireExceptText").ToString
        chkReq.Checked = True
        If Regex.IsMatch(ReqText.Text, "_") Then
            Dim message As String = "The selected Requirement contains some blanks to fill."
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
            sb.Append("alert('")
            sb.Append(message)
            sb.Append("')};")
            sb.Append("</script>")
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
            ReqText.Focus()
        End If
        Exit For

    Else
        Dim dtCurrentTable As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
        For Each row2 As GridViewRow In gvReq.Rows
            If dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count >= 6 Then
                If ReqText.Text <> "" Then
                    AddNewRow()
                End If
            End If
            Exit For
        Next

    End If

Next
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your first for each will exit on the first textbox no matter what.  Second in your else statement the check to see if the textbox is blank will always be true since you aren't checking the textbox for the row in the second loop.

Once you have those fixed if you are still having a problem post the code for the AddNewRow() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to work around it. Works great!

```
 Dim LastReqText As TextBox = DirectCast(gvReq.Rows(gvReq.Rows.Count - 1).FindControl("txtReqText"), TextBox)
        If LastReqText.Text <> "" Then
            AddNewRow()

        End If

        For i As Integer = 0 To gvReq.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim ReqText As TextBox = DirectCast(gvReq.Rows(i).FindControl("txtReqText"), TextBox)
            Dim chkReq As CheckBox = CType(gvReq.Rows(i).FindControl("chkReq"), CheckBox)

            If ReqText.Text = "" Then
                ReqText.Text = reader("RequireExceptText").ToString
                chkReq.Checked = True
                If Regex.IsMatch(ReqText.Text, "_") Then
                    Dim message As String = "The selected Requirement contains some blanks to fill."
                    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
                    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
                    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
                    sb.Append("alert('")
                    sb.Append(message)
                    sb.Append("')};")
                    sb.Append("</script>")
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
                    ReqText.Focus()
                End If
                Exit For

            End If

        Next
```